# Django Channels Group.send not working in python console?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I tried `Group(groupname).send` in the python console and it does not seem to work. Why is this?

This is my consumers.py arrangement:

```
def ws_connect(message):
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    Group(secure_group).add(message.reply_channel)


def ws_receive(message):
    # Nothing to do here
    Group(secure_group).send({
        "text": "Received {}".format(message.content['text'])
    })


def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group(secure_group).discard(message.reply_channel)
```

Routing:

```
from channels.routing import route
from App.consumers import (
    ws_connect,
    ws_receive,
    ws_disconnect
)

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_connect),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_receive),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect),
]
```

Terminal commands:

```
from channels import Group
#import secure_group here

Group(secure_group).send({ "text": "Tester" })
```

All my clients have never recieved the text.

`CHANNEL_LAYERS` config:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgiref.inmemory.ChannelLayer",
        "ROUTING": "App.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what is your `CHANNEL_LAYERS` config from `settings.py` ?

Comment: Updated with `CHANNEL_LAYERS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Inmemory` channel layer doesn't support `cross-process communication`. You can't perform Group send in other say terminal. Try with Redis backend you can send message.

From the doc `In-Memory`